# Can Wordpress functions be modified?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, overriding

I'm using the wp_list_bookmarks() function in wordpress to get links that have been added in the Wordpress back-end, things like blogroll etc.

My problem is that I need the list to come out in a certain way so that I can put it into columns, with about 5 links in each column.

By default it's just one big list. Is there a way that I can use PHP to alter the way this function posts the links so that I run a counter, and then after 5 links close off the current list and start a new one for the next column?

I basically need something like this:

```
<ul class="column-1">
    <li>link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
    <li>link4</li>
    <li>link5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="column-2">
    <li>link6</li>
    <li>link7</li>
    <li>link8</li>
    <li>link9</li>
    <li>link10</li>
</ul>
// etc...
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wordpress's get_bookmarks() function and then tailor the output to your liking. See here for an example:

```
<?php

$bookmarks = get_bookmarks( array(
            'orderby'        => 'name',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'category_name'  => 'Related Sites'
                      ));

// Loop through each bookmark and print formatted output
$column = 1;
$counter = 1;

echo "<ul class='column-$column'>";
foreach ( $bookmarks as $bm ) { 
    if ($counter >= 5)
    {
        $column++;
        $counter = 1; // reset the counter

        echo "</ul><ul class='column-$column'>";

    }
    printf( '<li><a class="relatedlink" href="%s">%s</a></li>', $bm->link_url, __($bm->link_name) );
    $counter++;
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_bookmarks#Examples

Comment: the code is not tested, but I hope you get the idea of what I am trying to propose. So my sincere apologies if there are any bugs (even if I have tried to ensure the code is bug free) :)

Comment: Makes sense, I will try it tonight and let you know how it goes. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to wordpress's [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Pluggable_Functions):

> Besides the hooks (actions and filters) described above, another way for a plugin to modify WordPress's behavior is to override WordPress functions. In fact, there is a small set of functions WordPress intends for plugins to redefine.

Unfortunately `wp_list_bookmarks` isn't on their list of functions that are considered "[pluggable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions)".

Maybe you can find something else that will fit your needs in the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into `wp_list_bookmarks()` from a plugin (that you need to write). That plugin can then manipulate the normal HTML that comes from the `wp_list_bookmarks()` function and return that manipulated HTML back to it, to be echoed or returned as normal.

The idea is to create (and activate!) a simple plugin like:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Diggersworld Bookmarks
Plugin URI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089883/can-wordpress-functions-be-modified
Description: Example plugin to customise output from wp_list_bookmarks
Version: 0.0
*/

function diggersworld_list_bookmarks($html)
{
    // Do your transformation here
    return '<p>Mmm pie.</p>';
}

add_action('wp_list_bookmarks', 'diggersworld_list_bookmarks');

?>
```

Save this as a file in your plugins folder, and activate it from within the Wordpress admin panel.  You will see that where your bookmarks used to be placed, the `Mmm pie.` text is there instead.  Modify that sample plugin to return your desired HTML using whatever method you like.

Since this is tying into a hook inside the `wp_list_bookmarks()` function, your templates should call `wp_list_bookmarks()` as normal.

Of course, the body of the plugin function could use code similar to that in [thesocialgeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089883/can-wordpress-functions-be-modified/6089990#6089990).